# FCM(firebase cloud message) onMessageCreate not called when app is not running

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use FCM to send notifications to my app. As it was told at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#backgrounded I create my own class, with override onMessageReceived method.

```
class PushService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        var intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("KeyI", "It is") //Just a debug pair
        var pendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            .run {
                addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent)
                getPendingIntent(
                    0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                )
            }
        Log.d("Myy", Gson().toJson(message.notification))
        var notif = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.notification_channel_id))
            .setContentText(message.notification?.body)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.push_icon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
                .notify(ServiceConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notif.build())
        } else {
            startForeground(ServiceConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notif.build())
        }
    }
}
```

When app is running, all is fine, I can receive this pain in main activity. But if I start the application by tapping on the notification, there are neither intent nor logging from onMessageReceived.

Does anyone give me an idea how to solve this?

Comment: You said you will receive the notifcation if the app is running? but is the method `onMessageReceived` trigger also?

Comment: If the application is running and opened, onMessageReceived works fine. Problem is it's not when I receive notification with closed app

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Turned out that instead of onMessageReceived it's needed a onHandleIntent to be overrided in FirebaseMessageService. Cause it works on each notification recieved